# Storing password when publishing SSDT project via Visual studio online and GIT

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to configure CI using Visual Studio Online. I've configured GIT and made the build. It is automatically building with every push I make. I want to automatically publish my changes to my database (stored on my server). I've created publish config for that, made the connection string there and put the password in that config. It is working great however is there any way to store the password (other than plain text)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem I have tried to fix myself (how do I have an open source project and still have builds with credentials in). The reality is that you can't store credentials in a public place and used by a public server without making them public.

You need to decide whether you trust VSO or not, if you do then you can give it your credentials and if you don't then you can't.

Normal things that you would do such as running the CI process under a service account or giving the account a certificate won't work for VSO because each build happens (seemingly from my testing) on a clean machine each time so you can't pre-configure security settings.

The best that you can really do is to only allow access to your database from known locations i.e. vso and whatever accesses the database rather than everywhere.

ed

Comment: can I restrict IPs just for 1 user/login?

Comment: Not built in but you could do it with a logon trigger http://www.connectsql.com/2012/07/sql-server-restrict-login-from-valid.html

Comment: yeah, I've found the same link. Thanks

Comment: Could you build w/ Integrated security, push the resulting output folder to the server, create a trigger file of some sort there, and schedule a local job that looks for that trigger and calls SQLPackage if it exists to push the changes? More work, but seems like it would get around your security concerns.